# Identifying a public wifi network using MAC its address

Tags: android, wifi, string-matching, mac-address, mac-spoofing

## The problem

I am trying to figure out whether a mobile app user is located within a given wifi network. In order to do the match, I am comparing the MAC address reported by the user to the one sampled manually in advance.

I have found that the router MAC address of users within the same network slightly differ, and I'm wondering if there's a way to figure out the reason behind the differences.

## Data

The following MAC addresses were reported by three different Android users connected to the same Starbucks wireless network:

```
02:18:1a:31:21:ce - User A
00:18:0a:31:21:ce - User B
02:18:1A:31:21:CE - User C
-+:--:+-:--:--:-- - Differences (+) (ignoring case)
```

The MAC addresses have 10 characters in common, and differ by two other characters. The wireless network requires sign-in with a username and password given by the cashier; all the customers in the shop used the same username/password combination.

## The question

Is there any logic behind the differences in the MAC addresses? Can I assume that similar router MAC address insinuate users within the same wifi network?

## Clarification

Clearly, MAC addresses can be spoofed to any arbitrary value. I wonder whether, in practice, similar MAC addresses are likely to belong to the same network - a.k.a the reason behind spoofing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pattern for a given network, they're hardware based.  If you see similar addresses, you just got lucky.  Here's the standard for MAC addresses:  http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/tut/macgrp.pdf

However, remember that just about every device is set up to be able to fake a MAC address or change them.  So really don't trust them.

Comment: Thanks. I think that this degree of similarity is more than sheer luck (the probabilities are just too little).

Comment: Like I said-  that's the standard.  The mac address are hardware based, and can be overridden by your OS.  So its absolutely luck.  In fact iOS and Windows Phone PURPOSELY randomize mac addresses for security. I think Android does as well https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7864813

Comment: Sure - note that I'm referring to the router's mac address, not the device's.

Comment: Oh, I missed that I appologize.  But its unlikely to have any dependable pattern- there's no benefit to it.  The only thing you want to ensure is that your address is unique within a network.  The high similarity you see is because the first 3 bytes is generally a manufacturer code.  Not that many router makers, and companies tend to buy a bunch of the same model for ease of maintenance.